# React on Visual Studio Not Starting When Setting SSL Certificate in package.json

Tags: reactjs, .net, windows, ssl, single-page-application

- I have a React.Js + .NET 6 combined project.
- When I run the app Visual Studio spins up a React development server that acts as a Proxy server. .NET WebAPI app runs on it's own in a different port
- Both have invalid SSL certificates.
- .NET app runs on - https://localhost:7148/
- React Dev Server (Proxying) runs on - https://localhost:44448

[image]

To resolve this, I created a Dev Certificate using the following dotnet command. This command can make a cert, trust it and also export CERT and it's private KEY files.

[image]

After this when I ran my .NET app, It successfully launched with a valid SSL.
I copied those 2 files (CERT and KEY) into where package.json resides and added this in package.json

[image]

However now the React development server is not starting. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

If I undo my changes on package.json, The SPA Proxy server starts and redirects to https://localhost:44448, However SSL is broken as well as React's hot-reload can't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd found the solution. Posting here to help anybody struggling with the same issue.

### **STEP BY STEP EASY SOLUTION ON WINDOWS**

1. Install Git for Windows - https://gitforwindows.org/
2. Then goto `'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin'`
3. Create a new file '`req.cnf`' with below content and save in above location

```
    [req]
    distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
    x509_extensions = v3_req
    prompt = no
    [req_distinguished_name]
    C = CA
    ST = ON
    L = Toronto
    O = MyCompany
    OU = MyDivision
    CN = localhost
    [v3_req]
    keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
    extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
    subjectAltName = @alt_names
    [alt_names]
    DNS.1 = localhost 
    DNS.2 = www.mydomainname.com
    DNS.3 = mydomainname.com
```

4. You can find `openssl.exe` in same folder
5. Run a terminal with administrative privileges on above location
6. Execute command:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048  -keyout server.key -out server.crt -config req.cnf -sha256`

7. This will produce 2 files in that same location.

- `server.crt`
- `server.key`

8. Open `server.crt` and click on install
9. Choose `Local Machine` in wizard
10. In next step choose `Place all certificate in the following store`
11. Click browse and select the store - `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`
12. Now your SSL certificate is trusted on your PC
13. Goto your React project. Go inside the folder where you see `package.json` file
14. Create a new folder `ssl` there
15. Paste above 2 files `server.crt` & `server.key` inside the folder
16. Open `package.json` and edit it to:

```json
 "scripts": {
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https && node aspnetcore-react",
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=./ssl/server.crt&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=./ssl/server.key&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
```

15. Close, Clean cache, reopen, and rebuild project
16. You're done

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sangeeth this really helped me. Great instructions